# textarea's `selectionStart` is not updated

Tags: javascript, textarea, selection-api

In the following javascript, the `selectionStart` of a textAarea is requested in the callback of an `onkeydown` event. However, the value obtained is not the current start of the selection, but that of the previous call to that event.

**How can I get the current caret position in this situation?**

```js
function printSelectionStart() {
  
    start = document.getElementById("tarea").selectionStart;
  
    document.getElementById("print").innerHTML="selection starts at "+start;
  
}
```

```html
<textarea id="tarea" onkeydown="printSelectionStart();">
</textarea>

<div id="print"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd use the [`onkeyup`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljaffqqe.php) event to check for that.

In your case

```
<textarea id="tarea" onkeyup="printSelectionStart();">
```

(although keeping scripts separated from markup would be better)